# Pyspark dataframe: crosstab or other method to make row label as new columns

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, crosstab

I have a pyspark dataframe as follows in the picture:

[image]

I.e. i have four columns: year, word, count, frequency. The year is from 2000 to 2015.

I could like to have some operation on the (pyspark) dataframe so that i get the result in a format as the following picture:

[image]

The new dataframe column should be : word, frequency_2000, frequency_2001, frequency_2002, ..., frequency_2015.

With the frequency of each word in each year coming from previous dataframe.

Any advice how I could write efficient code?

Also, please rename the title if you could come up some more informative.

Answer (score 8):

After some research, I found a solution: 
[image]

Comment: to facilitate the copy/paste :
topw_yes.groupBy("word").pivot("year").agg(first("count"))

Answer (score 0):

Now, the [crosstab](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crosstab.html) function can get the output directly :

```
topw_ys.crosstab("word", "year").toPandas()
```

Results:

```
 word_year  2000    2015
 0  mining  10      6
 1  system  11      12
 ...
```